# Elasticsearch NodeJS : How to return result

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to return a value out of a js function call as

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var client = elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});

var r="";

client.ping({
    // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
    requestTimeout: Infinity,

    // undocumented params are appended to the query string
    hello: "elasticsearch!"
}, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } else {
        console.log('All is well ping');
        function getmeresResult(err, result) {
            if (err) return err;
            console.log("Got res in ping "+result);
            return result;          
        }
        r=getmeres(client,getmeresResult);
        console.log("inner r is "+r);
        return r;
    }
});
console.log("outer r is "+r);
```

this gives me

```
Got res in ping 12,12,23
inner r is 12,12,23
```

the `console.log("outer r is "+r);` is never printed at all! why is that? how do i get the results 'out' of the client.ping function call?

Comment: the console is printed by nodeJS server (not by client) check how you have configurated it

Comment: if your code never reaches `console.log("outer r is" + r);` then you should debug it to understand **what** the code is actually doing. Based of this you can infer whether or not your `client.ping` is the cause for it, or something else with your back end

Comment: The `outer r is` line should be printed before `Got res in ping`. Check if it is.

Comment: you are correct. it prints out "". how to do i get the value out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the way node.js works. It is asynchronous, that means that the variable r in your example is printed when the callback invoked by elasticsearch is not yet called. I imagine that you want a global r variable in order to execute some code after the elasticsearch response that use the value stored there. In that case, if you want to use the callback interface you can:

- nest another function call from within the elasticsearch response;
- use a library that simplify this kind of job, like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

In the latter case you can probably use async.waterfall, and you can find an example of that with the elasticsearch js client [here](https://github.com/gvaldambrini/madam/blob/c953bf0896873d97e81d6a43fc3e198bd287b4d2/scripts/create_user.js).